# Circle CI cache for gradle projects

Tags: gradle, circleci

Circle CI suggests using the checksum dependencies.lockfile as part of a cache key for gradle projects. See https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/caching/#gradle-java

However, my gradle project does not have a file named "dependencies.lockfile". For maven projects, I use the checksum of the root POM.xml file and it works great.

What should I use as a cache key for gradle projects?

Answer (score 0):

You could use checksum of your `build.gradle` (or `build.gradle.kts`) file like

```
   - save_cache:
      name: Save gradle cache to cache
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle/caches/
      key: gradle-cache-{{ checksum "build.gradle" }}
```

Or if you use multi-project build you need extra step

```
   - run:
      name: Generate cache key
      command: cat $(find **/build.gradle) > build.gradle.all
   - save_cache:
      name: Save gradle cache to cache
      paths:
        - ~/.gradle/caches/
      key: gradle-cache-{{ checksum "build.gradle.all" }}
```